# Any python trick for flattening a dictionary and sorting it all at once?

Tags: python

I have this dictionary:

```
s = [{"label":["College Name"],"points":[{"start":939,"end":956,"text":"Kendriya Vidyalaya"}]},{"label":["College Name"],"points":[{"start":883,"end":904,"text":"Woodbine modern school"}]}]
```

I can sort it on start like this:

```
for annotation in sorted(s, key = lambda tup: tup['points'][0]['start']):
    print(annotation)
```

At the end of the day I need label, start and end. I know that I can access annotation in the loop and get to all the values I need, but then I'm pulling out the start point twice.

Is there any cool python trick to unpack values from a dictionary and sort on one of them all at once?

Comment: "At the end of the day I need label, start and end." Then how is this a sorting task? For the exact input you show, what should the exact output be, and why?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel  I want each label, start and end sorted by start.

Comment: So the goal is that you want to transform each entry into a (label, start, end) tuple, while also sorting those, in one fell swoop? Well - perhaps you know an elegant technique for transforming each element of a list? Perhaps you could pass that result to `sorted`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
for annotation in sorted(s, key = lambda tup: tup['points'][0]['start']):
    print(annotation["label"],annotation["points"][0]["start"],annotation["points"][0]["end"])
```

Or, only having to identify `start` by name once:

```
for annotation in sorted([(x["label"][0],x["points"][0]["start"],x["points"][0]["end"]) for x in s], key = lambda tup: tup[1]):
    print(annotation)
```

Comment: Well, I know I could do it that way :), I was trying to avoid having to access the "tup['points'][0]['start']" part twice :).

Comment: You need start for 2 independent things: the sort key and to appear in the result.  How might you specify both without identifying it for each?

Comment: @ScottHunter was seeing if there was a way to unpack it AND sort it in one shot. Guess not :(.

Comment: From the question - *"I know that I can access annotation in the loop and get to all the values I need"*

Answer (score 0):

> was seeing if there was a way to unpack it AND sort it in one shot.

The trick is to do the unpacking *first*.

What's the rule that tells us how to turn one of the dicts into the desired filtered data? Simple:

```
(item['label'], item['points'][0]['start'], item['points'][0]['end'])
```

How do we apply a rule like that to an entire list? Naturally, with a list comprehension or generator expression:

```
(
    (item['label'], item['points'][0]['start'], item['points'][0]['end'])
    for item in s
)
```

How do we sort those results? Using `sorted`, of course (since `sorted` creates a new result, it's no problem to pass a generator expression); our key function is now much simpler, since it only has to work with the filtered tuple. Thus:

```
sorted(
    (
        (item['label'], item['points'][0]['start'], item['points'][0]['end'])
        for item in s
    ),
    key = lambda filtered: filtered[1]
)
```

Comment: If you make tuples of `(start, end, label)` then no `key` function is required.

Comment: If that output order is satisfactory, then yes, that is simpler. That also allows for dropping the extra pair of parentheses around the generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dictionary keys are always in the order shown, you could convert the list of dictionaries to a rearranged list of tuples (that begin with the 'start' key/value pair). Then sort the tuples and re-form dictionaries from them.

```
s = [{"label":["College Name"],
     "points":[{"start":939,"end":956,"text":"Kendriya Vidyalaya"}]},
     {"label":["College Name"],
      "points":[{"start":883,"end":904,"text":"Woodbine modern school"}]}]

r = [*map(dict,sorted( ((*pd.items(),(lb,lv)) for d in s   
                       for (lb,(lv,*_)),(_,(pd,*_)) in [(*d.items(),)])))]

print(r)

[{'start': 883, 'end': 904, 'text': 'Woodbine modern school',
  'label': 'College Name'},
 {'start': 939, 'end': 956, 'text': 'Kendriya Vidyalaya', 
  'label': 'College Name'}]
```

If you don't want to flatten the 'points' key but only remove the unnecessary lists, you could do it like this:

```
r = sorted(({k:v for k,(v,*_) in d.items()} for d in s),
            key=lambda d:d["points"]["start"])

print(r)

[{'label': 'College Name', 
  'points': {'start': 883, 'end': 904, 'text': 'Woodbine modern school'}}, 
 {'label': 'College Name', 
  'points': {'start': 939, 'end': 956, 'text': 'Kendriya Vidyalaya'}}]
```